# Store jQuery objects in DB

Tags: database, jquery

I have a few draggable objects which I would like the user to drag around and then press "save" and return to the page the next day to drag them some more.
The draggable objects include dynamic html with event handlers etc.

I want to store these objects in the DB and then be able to reload them.

What would be a good approach to achieve this?

One possible way I came up with is to store all DOM code within a container div, in the DB as a string, and then insert it into the page and run scripts to add new event handlers for the specific elements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess storing them as a string is the best solution. Just put the column type "Long text" in the database!